# execute multiple cucumber feature files

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

When I submit a single feature file it works perfectly. I want to pass features folder path which has multiple feature files into runner script. Can anyone help to execute multiple feature files?

All feature files have same steps but data is different and file name is different.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty"}, features =
"C:\\TESTER\\Execution\\uidata\\featurefiles\\",
        glue={"com.test.auto.stepdefs"},dryRun=false) 

public class CucumberTest { 

}
```

I appreciate you help.

Comment: I always do it with tags.

Comment: what if different data exist in the same step?.

Comment: You can use a scenario outline. That can have 2 or more example tables, each table can have is own tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Java-Cucumber users  ::
Multiple Features are 
1.Smoketest 2. Logintest 
Then your Junit runner java file should look like

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)    
    @CucumberOptions 
    (features = "src/test/java/testStep/",#Path for the Feature files Folder.Given you have smoke.feature and login.feature files present in the Path#
    plugin ={"pretty","html:reports/test-report"},#Path for the Reports Html Folder#
    tags= {"@smoke,@login"})#Declaring multiple Feature names of files#
```

-- Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The features path must be relative to your project classpath. For example it can look like this:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"classpath:features_folder1", "classpath:features_folder2"}, ...)
```

or

```
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources")
```

Comment: I tired doing this but there is a after hook where the driver is getting quit and when the next feature file starts driver is throwing null exception. i tried to comment out after hook but sometimes I was able to run until third feature and sometimes it fails in the second. What would be the perfect way?. apreciate your help.

Comment: @sri I think you should ask that as a separate question as this is a significant issue by itself. Generally speaking, you have to make sure that you set up your `@Before` and `@After` hooks in a way that creates an environment ready for testing and cleans it properly after the test is done. For example, instead of closing the webdriver instance at the end of each test, like you have now, just clean the cookies and reuse the same webdriver instance.

Comment: got it eugene. I was able to handle the driver now. thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cucumber Command-Line Interface Runner (CLI Runner) `cucumber.api.cli.Main` and pass the path to the folder containing feature files as command line option.

**Example:**

```
java cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue com.my.stepdefn --plugin html:C:\testreports C:\features\
```

`com.my.stepdefn` is the package having the cucumber step definitions

`C:\features\` is the folder containing the feature files

`C:\testreports` is the folder where the cucumber html report will be generated.