# How do i access step definition class file from outside my project in cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

In My TestRunner File I want put two Step Definition path where one Step Definition will be inside my project and other would outside project.
When Im trying to use my Step definition which is outside project it saying "No Step Definition ..You can implement missing steps"
Any Solution For this

Comment: what do you mean by out of the project? Are you talking about 2 different projects which are interacting with each other? If yes, It means there is already a way of communication present between these two. You should look for the way how two different projects can interact, instead of accessing step definition.

Comment: Is the external step definitions jar mentioned in the classpath?

Comment: @GaurZilla I mean to say one step definition would be in SRC("src/test/java/com/Cucumber/StepDef") folder of my project and other step definition would be somewhere else like ("‪C:/StepDefinations") or in D\... folder Ex. glue ={"src/test/java/com/Cucumber/StepDef","‪C:/StepDefinations"}

Comment: @Grasshopper I didnt created any jar for it

Comment: Please refer to :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984295/execute-multiple-cucumber-feature-files might help